# How to select the overall price of rooms booked by the same person

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a table:

```
Create table rooms
(
roomNo int not null,
hotelNo int not null,
hotelName varchar (40) not null,
roomType varchar (40)
default 'standard' check (roomType in ('single', 'double', 'master', 
'standard', 'president')),
price decimal (8,2) check (price>=0 and price<=99999),
guestNo int null
)
```

`roomNo` and `hotelNo` are the primary key and `guestNo` is a foreign key.

The table is populated with values:

```
(101, 123456, 'Home','standard',300, 54321)
(101, 654321, 'Ibis','standard',300, Null)
(101, 987654, 'Hiton','president',15000, null)
(222, 987654, 'Hiton','standard',300, 12345)
(321, 987654, 'Hiton','master',1000, 11111)
(333, 123456, 'Home','single',100, null)
(333, 987654, 'Hiton','standard',300, 12345)
(567, 654321, 'Ibis','standard',300, null)
(888, 654321, 'Ibis','single' ,100, null)
(999, 654321, 'Ibis','double' ,200, null)
```

How can I answer the question "Select the overall price of rooms booked by the same person."?

I want get the sum price as 600 but based on this query I get 1900:

```
select sum(price)
from rooms r inner join guests g
on r.guestNo = g.guestNo and g.guestName = g.guestName
```

Comment: Sum(price) with those conditions is 1900 (300+300+1000+300)  Why would you expect 600?  What logic did you apply to give you that answer?

Comment: Base the question, guest 12345 book 2 rooms so need the price 600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the total price for each person then you need to group by that value:

```
select g.guestNo, sum(r.price)
from rooms r inner join guests g
on r.guestNo = g.guestNo
group by g.guestNo
order by g.guestNo;

   GUESTNO SUM(R.PRICE)
---------- ------------
     11111         1000
     12345          600
     54321          300
```

If you're only interested in guests with more than one room entry then you can add a `having` clause to check how many there were:

```
select g.guestNo, sum(r.price)
from rooms r inner join guests g
on r.guestNo = g.guestNo
group by g.guestNo
having count(r.roomNo) > 1
order by g.guestNo;

   GUESTNO SUM(R.PRICE)
---------- ------------
     12345          600
```

[Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Aggregate-Functions.html).

Your data model seems odd, incidentally; it seems strange to record a specific guest against the room. Maybe you should remove `guestNo` from that and have another table that links a room to a guest, perhaps for a date range. Price might vary too, so that might need to be in that booking table instead, or in yet another table (to allow for seasonal pricing etc.)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer I would fix it